# DataSetError in Docker Kedro deployment

Tags: docker, deployment, kedro

I try to deploy example Kedro starter project (pandas-iris).
I successfuly run it locally (`kedro run`), and then, having `kedro-docker` install, init a Docker, build image and push it to my registry.

Unfortunately, both `kedro docker run` and `docker run myDockerID/iris_image` generate the same error:

```
DataSetError: Failed while loading data from data set 
CSVDataSet(filepath=/home/kedro/data/01_raw/iris.csv, load_args={},
protocol=file, save_args={'index': False}).
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/kedro/data/01_raw/iris.csv'
```

It looks like the data catalog wasn't copied to the image/container.

I would appreciate Your help,

Many thanks :)

Andy

Answer (score 0):

If data catalog wasn't copy then you probably won't get the path? Is the data actually lives there?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: I had to comment `#data` entry in `.dockerignore` file. Original kedro-docker keeps data folder  ignored.

@mediumnok: thank you for the comment, no problem with path :)

Comment: I think the data is commented for a reason, often you don't want to package data inside the docker, but you would mount the storage to your docker with the docker run - v  command. If the goal is to just get everything run through for tutorial, that is perfectly fine.